# Understanding the expectation of the empirical spectral distribution

Tags: probability-theory, random-matrices

In the textbook "Topics in Random Matrix Theory" by Tao (or his blog https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/254a-notes-4-the-semi-circular-law/), the (normalized) empirical spectral distribution (ESD) of Hermitian matrix $M_n$ is defined as:
$$\mu_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}M_n}:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\delta_{\lambda_j(M_n)/\sqrt{n}}\,,$$
and the expectation $\textbf{E}\mu_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}M_n}$ is defined via Riesz representation theorem:
$\int_{R}\phi\, d\textbf{E}\mu_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}M_n} := \textbf{E}\int_{R}\phi\, d\mu_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}M_n}$.

$\textbf{(1)}$ **My first question** is that why should we define the expectation this way? Is it equally valid if we define the expectation as:
$$\textbf{E}\mu_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}M_n} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\delta_{\,\textbf{E}\lambda_j(M_n)/\sqrt{n}}\,.$$
That is, the nonrandom probability measure which puts equal weights on the expectation of each eigenvalue of the random matrix $M_n$.

$\textbf{(2)}$ It is stated later that by using the following proposition (Proposition 14 in the link https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/254a-notes-3-the-operator-norm-of-a-random-matrix/):
For any $\lambda>0$,
$$\textbf{P}(|\|M\|_{op}-\textbf{E}\|M\|_{op}|\geq\lambda)\leq C\exp(-c\lambda^2)\,,$$
for some absolute constants $C,c>0$.
We see that $\textbf{E}\mu_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}M_n}$ is uniformly sub-Gaussian:
$$\textbf{E}\mu_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}M_n}\{|x|>\lambda\}\leq Ce^{-c\lambda^2n^2}\,.$$
**My second question** is how should we see this?